# How can I make a Linux USB installation persistent from a running instance

Tags: kubuntu, livecd, liveusb

I am writing this from Kubuntu running from a USB (Started as "Demo")
How can I make the changes I make persistent? (From inside this running instance).ion

If not, how can I make it persistent before my next session?
(It is created in the standard way mentioned on  the Kubuntu download page)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get this, you can read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) about these methods.

Comment: I think these techniques are for preparing the USB?  Not for introducing it later, or fir a running instance.

Comment: Sure! I saw that you changed your question; If the changes made are the OS I'm afraid you must reassemble the working partition in RW, if the change affects only the end user, you may export your personal folder in a safe place, install a persistent version and then retrieve its configuration.

Comment: I did not change my question, I précised it :-).
It is for persisting changes like keyboard language, installed programs and Firefox addons (To write the question I had to install the LastPass addon, so that I could use GMail to log into this site)

Comment: Well, as I said before, may have mainly two types of changes, but some changes may be more complex to make persistent that its reconfiguration, due that your persistence will be housed in a new partition. But if you only need to export your settings Firefox, can make a merge your folder  ~/.mozilla and will saved all your plugins. +1 for running instance

Comment: Copying the whole home directory helps a lot.  If I use the command-line for installs and keep the history it is very quick to come up again.